# Redshift call procedure cross server

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to call a procedure on one redshift cluster from another (cross-region).  Can't use a lambda cause proc may take longer than 15 minutes (don't ask).  Right now I put a rds postgres inbetween them.

The RDS has `CREATE SERVER Cluster_B_dblink FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER dblink_fdw ...` and

```
create view proc_passthrough as
SELECT * FROM dblink('Cluster_B_dblink', 'call myproc()') AS t(a varchar);
```

Cluster A has `CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA rds_passthrough FROM POSTGRES ...`

Then calling `select * from rds_passthrough.proc_passthrough` on Cluster A runs that proc on Cluster B

This my only option to run the proc synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Redshift DATA API and Step Functions.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/etl-orchestration-using-the-amazon-redshift-data-api-and-aws-step-functions-with-aws-sdk-integration/